# Can I use JMESPath to get any items from a list if they exist in a different list?

Tags: jmespath

Consider I have 2 objects:

```
array1 = [{"name": "item1"}, {"name" : "item3"}]
```

and

```
array2 = [{"name": "item1", "anotherValue": 100},{"name": "item2", "anotherValue": 0}]
```

I'd like to do a check that if any items in array2 have a name that equals to any name in array1 output the anotherValue property.
So expected response would be:

```
100
```

Almost like I need a combination of search and contains.